# I am trying to have a paragraph that is hidden when the page loads, then do a show/hide jquery and also change the button name onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am very new to software development. I am creating a paragraph that when you click a button it will display a Spanish version of text instead of English. The English version will load, right now they both load and I am trying to get only the English to load and have the Spanish hidden. I want to toggle onclick between the two paragraphs. I also want to change the button from Spanish to English.

I thank you for any help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Modal Practice</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
         href="hidetest.css" />
    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    </head>

<body>


<div class="container" id="languageE">
    <p>
        Starting in 2014. 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container" id="languageS">
    <p>A partir del 2014...
    </p>
   </div>

    <div>
    <button class="Lang" id="myBtn">Español</button>
     </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myBtn').on('click', function() {
            $('#languageE').toggle();
        });


    });

    $('.Lang').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('Lang');
        if($this.hasClass('Lang'))
    {       
  $this.text('Español');
    }   else {
        this.text('English');
    }
    });
</script>




</body>



</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. When I run it, both paragraphs load. And when I click the button it doesn't change. However, the only thing that works is that it does hide the English part. Now that I want to switch the name of the button from Espanol to English, it takes two clicks to make the paragraph toggle work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script in code:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#languageS').hide();

            $('#myBtn').on('click', function() {
               if($(this).text() == "Español") {
                   $(this).text('English')
                   $('#languageE').hide();                                                           
                   $('#languageS').show();
               }
               else{
                   $(this).text('Español')
                   $('#languageS').hide();                                                           
                   $('#languageE').show();
               }
            });
      });
 </script>
```

Here is the fiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/43qnrek7/

Please let me know if it works for you and doesn't hesitate to ask me again if you face any problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much also. I just tried this one and it works also.

Comment: This one actually worked I created a test environment and it worked in Visual Studio Code, when I put it into my application on Visual Studio it didn't hide the Spanish paragraph. However when I test it in visual code it works just fine. I have the API at the top of the page in Visual Studio

Comment: Make sure you place this  $('#languageS').hide(); in document.ready or on load function whichever you used in you application.

Comment: Hi, I actually put it like you have it.

Comment: It didn't hide Spanish paragraph on load only or didn't hide the same on click too?

Comment: it didn't hide Spanish paragraph onload and now when i click the button, both paragraphs show when it is should display English. But in Visual Studio Code it works just fine.

Comment: Make sure you have used the id once in the HTML and please check once the id given to paragraph tag and the id defined in the script are exactly same.

Comment: Okay I will check. I haven't used the id tags anywhere else though.

Comment: Hi-I just want to let you know it works! I am sorry I am embarrassed for some reason when I typed in the code, I had a typo... So, thank you so, so much! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. This is you are expecting.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Modal Practice</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
         href="hidetest.css" />
    <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    </head>

<body>


<div class="container" id="languageE">
    <p>
        Starting in 2014. 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container" id="languageS">
    <p>A partir del 2014...
    </p>
   </div>

    <div>

    <button class="Lang" id="myBtn" value="Spanish">Español</button>
     </div>
    <script>
     $('#languageS').hide();
     $('.Lang').click(function() {

            var value=$(this).val();

            if(value=='Spanish')
            {
                $('#languageS').show();
                $('#languageE').hide();
                $(this).val('English');
                $(this).html('English')
            }
            else
            {
                $('#languageS').hide();
                $('#languageE').show();
                $(this).val('Spanish');
                $(this).html('Español')

            }


    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, Yes that works. However, how do I hide the Spanish paragraph when it loads so both paragraphs do not show initially?

Comment: Hi Thank you, yes, that worked! Thank you so much... I have been trying and searching this website for a week.

Comment: When I tried it in Visual Studio 2017 it didn't work. I put it in a test run in Visual Studio Code and it works just fine. I have the API at the top of the page in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, here is the solution you need

You can test the solution [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/p3bcmgtx/17/)
https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/p3bcmgtx/17/

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Modal Practice</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
             href="hidetest.css" />
        <script 
         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
        </head>

    <body>


    <div class="container" id="languageE" >
        <p>
            Starting in 2014. 
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="languageS" style="display:none;">
        <p>A partir del 2014...
        </p>
       </div>

        <div>
        <button class="Lang" id="myBtn">Español</button>
         </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myBtn').off().on('click', function() {
            $('#languageS').toggle();
            $('#languageE').toggle();
            let $this=$(this);
             $this.toggleClass('Lang');
             if($this.hasClass('Lang'))
             $this.text('Español');
             else
             $this.text('English');
        });
});
    </script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. The button name didn't change though. And want to show/hide one paragraph at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#div1').hide();
$('#preview').on('click', function() {
        $('#div1').toggle(300);
});
});
```

you can try like this with 2 div